# Set text for a textview in a custom list view

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an issue within my custom listview. Each row of the listview contains a button and a textview when the button is clicked a certain string is assigned to the textview. First , it worked like a charm then a strange issue occurs.

When I click the button of a specific row, the required string is assigned to the next textview (That's normal) but I noticed another textview in another row also has been assigned with the string.Thus, setext(string) has been assigned to two textviews in different rows with a single click.This is the code I use in my public getView

```
holder.bu6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

              holder.textViewNumber.setText(String.valueOf(counter[position]));

            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to use getter setter(POJO) for this

Comment: So how it  firstly worked for 2 months !!

Comment: Paste your full adapter code.

Comment: @ Ahmad Sayed Abdulrahman I don't know, but i am telling you solution on basis of your current issue

Answer (score 0):

you can create your list with model getter setter.

```
public class Category {

private String category;

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public Category(String category) {

    this.category = category;
}
```

}

```
now when you click on button then change string of that position in your list and notify your adapter.
```

Comment: @ Vishnu Saini I don't think he want to use getter setter. Because i already suggested him in above comments